# Pydev 3.0 + Eclipse + Google App Engine Debugging not working

Tags: eclipse, google-app-engine, pydev

I've been having problems getting debugging working with this setup for the past year.  Supposedly, this is fixed in the latest versions, but I just can't seem to get it to work.

I'm using Mac OSX 10.8.5, Eclipse Keplar, PyDev 3.0.0, and Google App Engine 1.8.8.

I set up a run configuration to point to dev_appserver.py, running my project.  That works fine.  My python version is 2.7.3, and everything works in normal mode.  When I try to run in debug mode, however, the app runs, the output specifically states:

```
pydev debugger: starting
pydev debugger: google app engine integration enabled
```

But after 20 seconds, the python process terminates with this error message:

```
'Launching New_configuration' has encountered a problem.
Timed out after 20.0 seconds while waiting for python script to connect.
Accept timed out
```

Execution works during those 20 seconds, because I can hit URLs connected to my app and see an effect.  Breakpoints do not work, though.  Is there something I need to do to get python to 'connect'?

Also - I should note that switching back to using 'old_dev_appserver.py' fixes this problem - debugging works fine when I do this.  But, this is not really a solution, because I need to use the latest socket additions in the newer releases.

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: Not again. This bug keeps coming back in every release. I just encountered it as well.

Comment: Same here, Windows 7 64bit, PyDev 3.0.0, GAE 1.8.8. I get 20 seconds too with the new server. By the way if you launch dev_appserver from command line, it works fine.

Comment: More info: it is not necessarily PyDev 3.0 to blame. I have switched to Windows 7 32 bit maichine with Juno and Pydev 2.8.1, yet the same GAE SDK 1.88. Same 20 sec problem, given the same set of parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like this is fixed in 1.9.0.  I also had to make sure to update PyDev to the latest (3.3.3 at the time of this writing).

One more thing to add, and this one really tripped me up (on MacOS) -
In Eclipse, under Run -> Run Configurations, set the Main Module to point to this location:

```
/usr/local/google_appengine/dev_appserver.py
```

NOT the symlink:

```
/usr/local/bin/dev_appserver.py
```

Answer (score 5):

temporary solution:

edit the pydev_app_engine_debug_startup.py file:

eclipse/plugins/org.python.pydev_${VERSION}/pysrc/pydev_app_engine_debug_startup.py

change the line that reads:

```
if ':' not in config.version_id:
```

to:

```
if ':' not in config.version_id or config.version_id.startswith('default:'):
```

Comment: Using Ubuntu 13.10, Eclipse 3.8 and PyDev 3.0 - encountered this issue and was able to solve it using this trick. Cheers.

Comment: This worked for me also. Switching to PyCharm IDE wasn't an option for me as it has a serious bug where breakpoints are ignored in some random GAE projects. This issue was reported and reproduced back in 2012, but still no fix is available.

Answer (score 0):

Well, finally I found the answer. It is a Google's bug.
It has been reported and acknowledged.
see [Debug is not working with PyDev again 1.8.8!](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=10390&q=pydev&colspec=ID%20Type%20Component%20Status%20Stars%20Summary%20Language%20Priority%20Owner%20Log)

Update: Until the bug is fixed I am using PyCharm. The pro version has 30 days trial and works with GAE. It works like, well, a charm. I may even consider switching to it from Elicpse/PyDev
But I am used to JetBrains tools with Android Studio recnetly, and WebStorm and Resharper in the past, so I know to find my way around their IDEs. Your milage may and will vary.

Answer (score 0):

Since the question, a new GAE has been released 1.8.9
Running GAE 1.8.9 with PyDev3.3.3 on Windows8.
This timeout issue still occurred. 
When I entered the temporary workaround changes to pydev_app_engine_debug_startup described in the earlier answer, then the browser could not connect to the app.

However, on backing out this change, not only did the 'Launching New_configuration' not appear, but the breakpoints worked.

More info on the Python Tool Support for the App Engine Development Server is here
https://docs.google.com/document/d/1CCSaRiIWCLgbD3OwmuKsRoHHDfBffbROWyVWWL0ZXN4/edit